# Express the curve of the cycloid in the form of a function $y=ϕ(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric, cycloid

I have the following problem.

If we express the curve of the cycloid in the form of a function $y=ϕ(x)$, show if it is possible to eliminate parameter $t$ in order to determine the cartesian representation of the cycloid.

Show that function $y=ϕ(x)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$(1 + (y')²) y = 2a$$

I know that the parametric equations for the cycloid are:

$$x=r(t—\sin(t)),\quad y=r(1—\cos(t))$$

I really do not know what is a $y=ϕ(x)$ function, or how can use that function to solve the rest of the problem

Could you please show me what is this function, give me an example on how to solve this, or maybe give me a link to a website where I can learn about this.

Please excuse my English. Thanks.

Comment: I find the question confusing. As far as I know, it is *impossible* to explicitly find such a function $\phi$. Of course, it exists abstractly by the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: You say you don't know what a $y=\phi(x)$ function is... Don't be afraid by the $\phi$.... Do you know what a (cartesian) equation $y=f(x)$ is ? Then, ask Google with "cycloid cartesian equation"... you will find [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Cycloid_in_Cartesian_Coordinates)

Comment: @JeanMarie That link is garbage. The equation is valid for only a very small portion of the curve. Interestingly, it gives $x$ as a function of $y$, which we know cannot hold on even one arch of the cycloid.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin You are right. I hadn't paid enough attention...

Comment: At any rate, you can derive that differential equation by implicit differentiation of the parametric equations. Make an effort to do that. By solving that differential equation, you can *locally* get $x$ as a function of $y$, but not vice versa. (But you could just as well do that directly from the parametric equations.) The horizontal line test shows that you cannot obtain $x$ as a function of $y$ on more than half an arch of the cycloid.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, I have a better understanding of the cycloid now

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I was confused, i thought a y=ϕ(x) function was something else in this case, thank you.